# Load every file in mysql with unique id in MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert file in mysql with an unique id

load data local infile 'F:\makarand\mak.txt' 
 into TABLE fileocntent;

This command is working fine but i have one more column for id and i want to insert every file with unique id in mysql table

load data local infile 'F:\makarand\mak.txt' 
 into TABLE fileocntent;

I want to add unique id in another column for this file

Comment: 'want to insert every file with unique id in mysql table'  - i'm not clear what you mean by this do you mean a unique id for every row OR an id to identify the file the row came from?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an autoincrement column to your table to be the unique ID column which will take care of creating and incrementing the ID value automatically. The syntax for [LOAD DATA INFILE SYNTAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-list) can specify a list of fields that the data should go in. So you can write the code with a list of field names excluding the ID column and that will do the trick.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:\makarand\mak.txt' INTO TABLE filecontent (field1, field2, ...)
```

Comment: i agree to this.  Reading the LOAD DATA INFILE SYNTAX article is big help.